# Android: buttons touch area has left shifted?

Tags: android, button, touch

I have a list of toggle buttons to be placed to top-right corner of the screen and have some padding such that they would not be very closed to screen boundary.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
      a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      a:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <LinearLayout
      a:id="@+id/header"
      a:orientation="horizontal"
      a:layout_width="wrap_content"
      a:layout_height="wrap_content"
      a:paddingTop="5px"
      a:layout_gravity="top"
      a:paddingRight="15px"
      a:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  >

    <ToggleButton a:id="@+id/button1"
        a:layout_width="40px"
        a:layout_height="40px"
        a:background="@drawable/button1"
        a:textOn=""
        a:textOff=""
    />

    <ToggleButton a:id="@+id/button2"
        a:layout_width="40px"
        a:layout_height="40px"
        a:background="@drawable/button2"
        a:textOn=""
        a:textOff=""
    />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The buttons are placed correctly. However, when I touch right button , it is not get checked.
Until I touch on left bound of the button, it got checked. 
The vaild touch area is left shifted. Why do this happen?

Comment: Remove the `top` gravity from the `LinearLayout`(its useless anyway) and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: @Luksprog. I have followed your advise but the touch area is still left shifted.